# UserControl with DependencyProperty in MVVM Light

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, mvvm-light

I have a UserControl that add a  DependencyProperty for it .

```
    public const string TextValuePropertyName = "TextValue";
      public string TextValue
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(TextValueProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TextValueProperty, value);
        }
    }
     public static readonly DependencyProperty TextValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        TextValuePropertyName,
        typeof(string),
        typeof(FormatUserControl),
        new UIPropertyMetadata());
```

and use it in another Usercontrol

```
       <local:FormatUserControl   TextValue="{Binding Subject,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
```

When i use this don't set value for this property when i change `Subject` value?

Comment: How do you know? You haven't registered a [PropertyChangedCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.PropertyChangedCallback.aspx) with the dependency property metadata. Note that WPF does usually *not* call the setter of the property wrapper, as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Your FormatUserControl is the class and you should register the property for it not for the NumberFormatUserControl like this (I am not aware what is the relationship between the two user controls):

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    TextValuePropertyName,
    typeof(string),
    typeof(FormatUserControl),
    new UIPropertyMetadata());
```